# g++ does not find cross compiled boost headers

Tags: c++, boost, arm, g++, point-cloud-library

---

**Edit**

Added more information to reproduce the error.

---

I want to cross compile PCL for Raspberry Pi 3B+ (armv7l) with GCC 8.3. For this, I need boost 1.67 as this is my current library inside Pi. This is the way I'm doing it:

```
sudo debootstrap stretch crossdev_folder
sudo chroot crossdev_folder
apt install -y unzip cmake cmake-curses-gui xz-utils
cd /root/
```

then I download AArch32 target with hard float (arm-linux-gnueabihf) GCC 8.3 from [here](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads/8-3-2019-03) and copy its content to `/usr/`

```
tar -xvf gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz
cd gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/
rm *.txt && cp -r ./* /usr/ && cd /root/
rm -r gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-linux-gnueabihf/
```

and then I cross compile libboost 1.6.7

```
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/boost_1_67_0.zip
unzip boost_1_67_0.zip && rm boost_1_67_0.zip && cd boost_1_67_0/
./bootstrap.sh
sed -i 's/using gcc ;/using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ ;/' project-config.jam
./bjam install toolset=gcc-arm --prefix=/usr -sNO_ZLIB=1 -sNO_BZIP2=1
```

to be sure I have installed them I go to /usr/include/ and the boost/ folder is there with all the headers. (For example boost/mpl/assert.hpp)

```
root@felipe:/root# cd /usr/include/
root@felipe:/usr/include# ls boost/mpl/assert.hpp 
boost/mpl/assert.hpp
```

then I cross compile and install OpenCV-3.4.9 (because I need it too) and and finally I try to cross compile PCL like this

```
# First install some dependencies
apt-get install -y libflann-dev:armhf libeigen3-dev:armhf libglu1-mesa-dev:armhf freeglut3-dev:armhf mesa-common-dev:armhf

# Download PCL
cd /root/
wget https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases/download/pcl-1.11.1/source.zip
unzip source.zip && rm source.zip && cd pcl/

# Do CMake
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
-DWITH_VTK=OFF ..
```

Here I find the first problem as CMake cannot find FLANN - which has been already installed with apt and I can find its .pc in

```
root@felipe:/root/pcl/build# ls /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/
dri.pc               libdrm_nouveau.pc    xau.pc               xcb-xfixes.pc
flann.pc             libdrm_omap.pc       xcb-dri2.pc          xcb.pc
gl.pc                libdrm_radeon.pc     xcb-dri3.pc          xdamage.pc
glu.pc               libdrm_tegra.pc      xcb-glx.pc           xdmcp.pc
ice.pc               libdrm_vc4.pc        xcb-present.pc       xext.pc
libdrm.pc            pthread-stubs.pc     xcb-randr.pc         xfixes.pc
libdrm_amdgpu.pc     sm.pc                xcb-render.pc        xshmfence.pc
libdrm_exynos.pc     x11-xcb.pc           xcb-shape.pc         xt.pc
libdrm_freedreno.pc  x11.pc               xcb-sync.pc          xxf86vm.pc
```

So I have to do cmake with `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` to specify the installation prefix of all the :armhf libraries previously installed. I get some Boost warnings due to cmake version but it seems to fn find boost libraries properly

```
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:761 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106700
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:865 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1470 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/pcl_find_boost.cmake:33 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:462 (include)


-- Boost version: 1.67.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   system
```

some changes for cross compilation :

```
# remove some lines from CMake files
sed -i '11,16d' ../cmake/pcl_find_sse.cmake && sed -i '10 a \ \ \ \  list(APPEND SSE_FLAGS "-marm")' ../cmake/pcl_find_sse.cmake
```

And here, when I try to compile, it fails because it cannot find boost headers
**edit** : add VERBOSE=1 to make

```
    root@felipe:/root/pcl/build# make VERBOSE=1
/usr/local/bin/cmake -S/root/pcl -B/root/pcl/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /root/pcl/build/CMakeFiles /root/pcl/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/pcl/build'
make -f common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/build.make common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/pcl/build'
cd /root/pcl/build && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /root/pcl /root/pcl/common /root/pcl/build /root/pcl/build/common /root/pcl/build/common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/root/pcl/build/common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/root/pcl/build/common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/root/pcl/build/common/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/root/pcl/build/common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target pcl_common
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/pcl/build'
make -f common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/build.make common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/pcl/build'
[  0%] Building CXX object common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/point_types.cpp.o
cd /root/pcl/build/common && /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -DPCLAPI_EXPORTS -I/root/pcl/build/include -I/root/pcl/common/include -isystem /usr/include/eigen3 -isystem /root/pcl/recognition/include/pcl/recognition/3rdparty  -Wabi=11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-format-extra-args -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-conversion -marm -ffloat-store -fopenmp -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -fPIC   -fopenmp -std=c++14 -o CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/point_types.cpp.o -c /root/pcl/common/src/point_types.cpp
In file included from /root/pcl/common/include/pcl/type_traits.h:40,
                 from /root/pcl/common/include/pcl/memory.h:46,
                 from /root/pcl/common/include/pcl/impl/point_types.hpp:41,
                 from /root/pcl/common/include/pcl/point_types.h:349,
                 from /root/pcl/common/src/point_types.cpp:37:
/root/pcl/common/include/pcl/point_struct_traits.h:42:10: fatal error: boost/mpl/assert.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>  // for BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/point_types.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/src/point_types.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/pcl/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:122: recipe for target 'common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/pcl/build'
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea of what I'm missing? Thank you!

### **Update**

When I install boost in /usr/local with --prefix=/usr/local the compiler can actually find the headers (I also have to move flann headers).
I finally get another error but this is mostly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56244159/13154650)

Comment: can you run your make with `VERBOSE=1`?

Comment: Thanks! I edited the output of make with VERBOSE=1. Apparently there is not any -I/usr/include or -I/usr/local/include

Answer (score 0):

If cmake could not add the path automatically. Use: `link_directories` and `include_directories`.

You can also export CXXFLAGS before runing your cmake command. From  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_FLAGS_INIT

> CMake may prepend or append content to the value based on the
> environment and target platform For example, the contents of a xxxFLAGS environment variable will be prepended, where xxx will be language-specific but not necessarily the same as  (e.g. CXXFLAGS for CXX, FFLAGS for Fortran, and so on).

An other solution (not the best) since you are already modifying some files, is to modify directly the flags.make to add include path and link.txt to add the path with -L option.

Comment: Added small toolchain file 
'''
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-isystem /usr/include")
'''
and ran it as
'''
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-linux-gnueabihf.cmake -DWITH_VTK=OFF -DWITH_OPENGL=OFF ..
''' 
and got some weird preprocessing errors 'missing binary operator before token' because the flags are still being replaced by -isystem /usr/include

Comment: Try : export CXXFLAGS= "flags you want";cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../arm-linux-gnueabihf.cmake  .... . I think you donet need to sed cmake_cxx_flags_init in your toolchain file. Be careful with your cache also( clean your build directory).

Comment: @afvmil did it worked with the suggestion i made or no?

Comment: not really, I posted an answer with what I did to make it work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct reason but apparently the compiler has some default directories where it looks for headers and libraries [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58011322/13154650). So I did

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v -x c -E -
```

and I got

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/include-fixed
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8.3.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 /usr/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/include
```

Then I cross compiled and installed boost, flann and Eigen in `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf` and cmake in pcl/build folder as

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ \
-DWITH_VTK=OFF \
-DWITH_OPENGL=OFF \
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf ..
```

and it compiled